# NuxtJS load cjs modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm try to use third-party libraries in my `NuxtJS` project. This dependencies has `cjs` and `mjs` extensions.

Simple import

```
import { DataModel } from '@glazed/datamodel'
import { DIDDataStore } from '@glazed/did-datastore'
```

raised error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                            friendly-errors 16:55:12


ERROR  in ./node_modules/@glazed/datamodel/dist/lib.cjs                                                                           friendly-errors 16:55:12

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:1104)                                                                                     friendly-errors 16:55:12
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

My `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
    transpile: [
      'dids',
      'did-jwt',
      '@glazed/tile-loader',
      '@glazed/did-datastore',
      '@glazed/datamodel', 
    ],
    extend(config) {
      ...
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.mjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
      })
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.сjs$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
      })
      ...
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Hi, do you still have the same error after those settings?

Comment: Yes. This is the essence of the question.

Comment: You configuration looks okay! Did you find something in the related package'S Github issues? This is probably a Webpack4 incompatibility from the few searches I did on Nuxt own issues with the same keywords.